# How can I have slick generates query without double quotes?

Tags: sql, oracle, scala, slick

I'm trying to using Slick to interact with Oracle DB. The mapping is:

```
trait EntityTable extends DataBaseConfig{

  import driver.api._

  class Log(tag: Tag) extends Table[LogEntity](tag,"LOG_SCHEMA.A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME") {
    def id = column[Option[Long]]("LOG_ID",O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
    def log = column[String]("LOG_TEXT")

    def * = (LOG_ID, LOG_TEXT) <> ((LogEntity.apply _).tupled, LogEntity.unapply)
  }
  protected val getLogs = TableQuery[Log]
}
```

From the debugger I see the SQL generated is:

```
select "LOG_ID", "LOG_TEXT" from "LOG_SCHEMA.A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME"
```

This gives me an

```
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
```

How can I have slick generates query without double quotes? Or is there a better way to deal with long table name in different schemes which I do not have control over? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can not have names (table, index, view) longer than 30 characters. In your example I guess you have a mistake, instead of

```
"LOG_SCHEMA.A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME"
```

try this:

```
"""LOG_SCHEMA"."A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME"""
```

or this:

```
"\"LOG_SCHEMA\".\"A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME\""
```

It does not matter how the table has been created A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME can not have more than 30 characters.

Comment: I used """LOG_SCHEMA"."A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME""", It generated "select "LOG_ID", "LOG_TEXT" from "LOG_SCHEMA"".""A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME""

Comment: what about  "\"LOG_SCHEMA\".\"A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME\"" ?

Comment: Another option would be to connect to DB useing LOG_SCHEMA username instead you could use just "A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME"  in this case you do not have to qualify table_name with schema_name, or to create a sysnonim for LOG_SCHEMA.A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME

Comment: With "\"LOG_SCHEMA\".\"A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME\"" , it yields """LOG_SCHEMA"".""A_TABLE_WITH_VERY_LONG_NAME""". I don't have control over LOG_SCHEMA username as mentioned originally.